# Go interface to enforce same argument type between methods (but can be any type)

Tags: go, interface

The title is confusing, I'm sure, but it's hard to describe what I mean.

I want to create a Go interface that has two methods; the first one returns a value, and the second one accepts a value. I want to ensure that method 1 returns the same type as method 2 accepts, without specifying what the type is (other than it being a struct). For example:

```
type MyInterface interface {
    Method1() MyType
    Method2(MyType) error
}
```

Where `MyType` can be any type (of struct), as long as it's the same in both Method 1 and Method 2.

Is there any way to do this in Go?

**EDIT:**

Based on @iLoveReflection's answer, I've tried the following:

```
package main

type MyInterface interface {
    GetType() interface{}

    UseType(input interface{})
}

type MyImplementation struct{}

type MyType struct {
}

func (i MyImplementation) GetType() MyType {
    return MyType{}
}
func (i MyImplementation) UseType(input MyType) {
    return
}

func test(input MyInterface) {
    return
}

func assertArgAndResult() {
    var v MyImplementation
    v.UseType(v.GetType())
}

func main() {
    test(MyImplementation{})
}
```

So basically, I'm specifying an interface (`MyInterface`), and I want to ensure that a given implementation of that interface (`MyImplementation`, which would be created by the user of my package) meets the requirement stated in the original post.

`assertArgAndResult()` is working as expected, and ensures that `MyImplementation` meets the requirements. However, I get a compile error in the `main()` function:

```
cannot use MyImplementation literal (type MyImplementation) as type MyInterface in argument to test:
    MyImplementation does not implement MyInterface (wrong type for GetType method)
        have GetType() MyType
        want GetType() interface {}
```

Comment: What you're describing is generics, which are not supported by Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following function to a package to ensure that the input and output types match at compile time:

```
func assertArgAndResult() {
    var v MyInterface
    v.Method2(v.Method1())
}
```

This function will not be included in the executable as long as the function is not called.

There is no compile time check that will ensure that `MyType` is a struct type as specified in the question.

The reflect package can be used to check type types completely.

```
// checkItf returns true of the interface value pointed to by
// pi has Method1 with some return type T and Method2 with
// argument type T.
func checkItf(pi interface{}) bool {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(pi)
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return false // or handle as error
    }
    t = t.Elem()
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Interface {
        return false // or handle as error
    }
    m1, ok := t.MethodByName("Method1")

    // Method1 should have no outputs and one input.
    if !ok || m1.Type.NumIn() != 0 || m1.Type.NumOut() != 1 {
        return false
    }

    // Method2 should have one input and one output.
    m2, ok := t.MethodByName("Method2")
    if !ok || m2.Type.NumIn() != 1 || m2.Type.NumOut() != 1 {
        return false
    }

    e := reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()
    s := m1.Type.Out(0)

    // The type must be a struct and
    // the input type of Method2 must be the same as the output of Method1 and
    // Method2 must return error.
    return s.Kind() == reflect.Struct &&
        m2.Type.In(0) == s &&
        m2.Type.Out(0) == e
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func init() {
   if !checkItf((*MyInterface)(nil)) {
      panic("mismatched argument and return time son MyInterface")
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks great for runtime checking, thanks! Is there no way to do compile-time checking?

Comment: That seems to work partially, but still having a compile error. Please see my edit in the question.